# Encode/ Represent a image into smaller text

Tags: image-processing, encoding, base64, qr-code, image-compression

I have a image whose base64 is roughly 10K characters long. I have to put this image in a qr code, due to size limitations of QR code, I cant put the entire base64 in it. Can I somehow reduce/encode/compress the image to around 1K characters. I need to put the image in QR code, not as a link or anything else.

Any suggestions on what compression/encoding could be used here.

Comment: If you shared the image it may help.

Comment: It is a photograph of myself. Jpeg format. Dimensions: 160 × 200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **ImageMagick** at the command line to try and reduce the size of your image but it isn't going to be pretty.

```
convert input.jpg -strip -define jpeg:extent=1000 result.jpg
```

The `-define jpeg:extent=1000` means you want the resulting image to be under 1,000 bytes regardless of how low the quality is. Good luck!

Here is Theresa May at under 1,000 bytes for example:

[image]